# adding an intent to an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am very new to android programming. I am using android 4.2 and I have a main activity which consists of 3 tabs in an actiobBar.
I would like to start another activity (a mapActivity), if the user clicked on a certain tab.
so I would create an intent if the user clicks on the tab.
Here is the code:

```
     @Override
     public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
         // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
         // the ViewPager.
         mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

         if(tab.getText().equals("Map")){

            Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MapDisplayActivity.class);
            this.setIntent(intent);
            startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

but whenever I click on "Map", I lose the tabs. It seems like this starts an activity on its own and stops the first one. What I would've liked is to have the map, under the tab named "Map".

Can you help me with giving any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approach here that you are mixing and you can't really mix the two:

1) you can use Fragments which is what you seem to be using with the actionbar. But then you need to implement the map in a Fragment see http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html
and 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

2) The other way is the old way using separate activities for each tab with TabActivity  where you create new Activities like you started to do with the mapActivity, but this way is deprecated as of Honeycomb.

Answer (score 0):

In Android an intent is used to communicate with other activities, and startActivitiy launches a new one outside of yours. For a tutorial about intents look here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/

Instead what you want to do is place whatever view you use to show the map under the tab layout and then don't use intents at all.

But in general you need to fully understand what an activity is before you continue as it is a fundamental concept of Android: here is a link:http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

Goodluck!